# Querying average with a function of column in Rails

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, squeel

I'm using Rails 4 in a web app, Postgresql database and squeel gem for queries.

I have this function in my model statistic.rb

```
def properties_mean_ppm(mode, rooms, type, output_currency_id)
  sql_result = properties(mode, rooms, type).select{
    avg(price_dolar / property_area).as(prom)
  }
  avg = sql_result[0].prom
  final_avg = change_currency(avg, DOLAR_ID, output_currency_id)
  return final_avg.to_f
end
```

price_dolar and property_area are columns in the properties table.
It works fine in Rails console and displays the result, but when I use it on the controller it gives an error:

> ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (missing attribute: id)

And indicates the line

```
avg = sql_result.to_a[0].prom
```

I also tried using sql_result[0].prom or sql_result.take or sql_result.first, they all have the same error.
The sql_result is this:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Property >]>
```

This is the action called in the controller

```
def properties_mean_ppm
  @statistic = Statistic.find(params[:id])
  mode = params[:mode] ? params[:mode] : ANY_MODE
  type = params[:type] ? params[:type] : ANY_TYPE
  one_room = @statistic.properties_mean_ppm(mode, 1, type, UF)
end
```

I know how to get the result using only SQL without activerecord but that would be very inefficient for me because I have lots of filters called before in the properties() function

Answer (score 0):

Seems like calling that from the properties object made the controller to expect a Property with an id as a result. So I made it work without squeel.

```
sql_result = properties(mode, rooms, type).select(
  "avg(precio_dolar / dimension_propiedad) as prom, 1 as id"
)
```

And giving a fixed id to the result